# How to remove single quotes(&#039;) in between href /src in php

Tags: php, regex

Suppose string is 
`<a href=&#039;fooo&#039; >hai</a><img src=&#039;foo&#039; >hai&#039;b`

i want to remove all  `&#039;` in between src/href

So the result should be  like this

```
<a href=fooo>hai</a><img src=foo>hai&#039;b
```

It should effect only the tags `<a><img>`

Comment: So your input string is " haihai'b", and your output string is " haihai'b"? Aren't they the same?

Comment: i am not getting this " in between src/href " part . which part do you mean by that ?

Comment: do you want to remove every '&#039' inside '<a>' tag and '<img>' tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a\K|\G(?!^)[^>]*?\K&#039;|<img\K|\G(?!^)[^>]*?\K&#039;
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/8